# Types using XTEA encryption funct

Tags: encryption, types, cryptography

I'm very interested in cryptography, and since I like programming too, I decided to make a little program to encrypt files using XTEA encryption algorithm.
I got inspired from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA), and so I wrote this function to do the encryption (To save space, I won't post the deciphering function, as it is almost the same):

```
void encipher(long *v, long *k)
{
    long v0 = v[0], v1 = v[1];
    long sum = 0;   
    long  delta = 0x9e3779b9;
    short rounds = 32;
    for(uint32 i = 0; i<rounds; i++)
    {
        v0 += (((v1 << 4) ^ (v1 >> 5)) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]);
      sum += delta;
        v1 += (((v0 << 4) ^ (v0 >> 5)) + v0) ^ (sum + k[(sum>>11) & 3]);
    }
    v[0] = v1;
    v[1] = v1;
}
```

Now when I want to use it, I wrote this code:

```
long data[2]; // v0 and v1, 64bits
data[0] = 1;
data[1] = 1;

long key[4]; // 4 * 4 bytes = 16bytes = 128bits
*key = 123; // sets the key

cout << "READ: \t\t" << data[0] << endl << "\t\t" <<  data[1] << endl;
encipher(data, key);
cout << "ENCIPHERED: \t" << data[0] << endl << "\t\t" << data[1] << endl;

decipher(data, key);
cout << "DECIPHERED: \t" << data[0] << endl <<  "\t\t" <<  data[1] << endl;
```

I always get either run-time crash or wrong decipher text:
[image]

I do understand the basics of the program, but I don't really know what is wrong with my code. Why is the enciphered data[0] and data[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) the same? And why is deciphered data completely different from the starting data? Am I using the types wrong?
I hope you can help me solving my problem :) .

- Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
v[0] = v1; // should be v[0] = v0
v[1] = v1;
```

Also, you only set the first 4 bytes of the key. The remaining 12 bytes are uninitialized.
Try something like this:

```
key[0] = 0x12345678;
key[1] = 0x90ABCDEF;
key[2] = 0xFEDCBA09;
key[3] = 0x87654321;
```

[The fixed code](http://pastebin.com/WeYT5fsN) gives me this output:

```
READ:           1
                1
ENCIPHERED:     -303182565
                -1255815002
DECIPHERED:     1
                1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I can see my stupid mistype in the v1 and v0.
Can you please explain the setting of the bytes in the key? I dont really know much about hexadecimals, but can't I just set the key[1...3] to 0?
Unfortunately, your answer did not solve the main problem, but I'm sure it helped a lot!

Comment: @Janman: Sure you can set key[1], key[2] and key[3] to 0, but you need to set them to *something*. If you do not set them to anything they are unintialized and will just have whatever value is randomly in that part of memory. Didn't it work with the change? Do you perhaps have a similar problem in `decipher`?

Comment: Thank you very much, now I made it work. Just one more little question, if I may:
When I want to read data from a file, can I just use:
'myIfstream.readsome((char*)&data[0],4);' and then use this procedure to encipher it?